# Where to find a List of Possible XML-Attributes of a Specific Android Widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

Would like to know if there is any resource on the web that conveniently lists all possible attributes of an XML-element representing a specific Android widget (e.g., `<TextView>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) example for TextView. Section "XML Attributes".

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc for the widget has a section for the [XML Attributes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#lattrs)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! (should have found myself)